# "This is a picture of page that I don't understand + it"?

Tags: sentence-structure

I have a picture of a page that in it there is text that I don't understand. 
Should I say the pronoun "**it**" in the end of the following sentence or not?

> "This is a picture of page that I don't understand **it**"

or

> "This is a picture of page that I don't understand"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence you have *two clauses*.

The first, the main clause, has a subject ("this") and a predicate ("is"), and also *an object* "a picture of page" (needs to be "a picture of ***the*** page").

The second, a subordinate clause (AKA a dependent clause), also has a subject ("I") and a predicate ("don't understand").

The two clauses are connected by the word "that", which is a *relative pronoun*.  It plays the role of the **object** of the *subordinate clause*.

You can rewrite your single sentence as two:

> This is a picture of the page.  I don't understand ***it***.

The second sentence has its own object, "**it**".  When the two sentences are compound into one, the place of the object ("it") is taken by the *relative pronoun* ("that"), which means that, because "understand" already has an object in "that", the "it" has to be removed:

> This is a picture of the page ***that*** I don't understand.

Comment: Beautiful explanation! I liked your answer. By the way, this structure as far as I know is syntactical called "complex sentence" (because of the relative pronoun) while the two that you divided are called "simple sentences".